# How to pass long number through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I want to convert numberLong date from the mongo db database into dd/mm/yyyy format in javascript.

When I put direct hardcoded value like the following code, it gives me correct result:

```
function getDateIfDate(d) {
    var m = d.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//);
    return m ? (new Date(+m[1])).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric'}) : d;
}

console.log(getDateIfDate("/Date(1460008501597)/"));
```

Here is my code :

```
for(var i=0;i<keys;i++)
                {
                var tr="<tr>";
                tr+= "<td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td>"
                tr+="<td>"+positionList[i]["fromDate"]+"</td>";
                var j = (positionList[i]["fromDate"]);
                console.log("value of j is =========="+j);
                console.log(getDateIfDate("/Date(j)/")); // actual conversion should happen here
}
```

What changes I should make in my code to get the date in required format?

Comment: what is the value of j?

Comment: hi, value of j is 1496707200000

Answer (score 3):

```
tr+="<td>"+positionList[i][new Date("fromDate").toLocaleString()]+"</td>";
```

try to replace old line by this new one

Answer (score 2):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for your case. It's really simple to use, if you want to format your date to **DD/MM/YYYY**, just add the row below:

```
var formattedDate = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should invoke function like this  `getDateIfDate("/Date("+j+")/");`

instead of `getDateIfDate("/Date(j)/")` this means you are passing string `"/Date(j)/"`.

```js
 
function getDateIfDate(d) {
    var m = d.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//);
    return m ? (new Date(+m[1])).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric'}) : d;
}


var j= 1460008501597;

console.log(getDateIfDate("/Date("+j+")/"));
```